Apply large number of decision tree rules to SQL data
I want to apply rules that I've created from modelling on data using a decision tree to unseen data. I've parsed the rules to get a CASE WHEN statement like so:
CASE
    WHEN variable_1 = "Value1" 
    THEN 1 
    WHEN variable_1 = 2 AND variable_2 = 'Variable2_value1'
    THEN 2
.......
END AS NODE

However for some of the models created, I have 20k leaf nodes and ~1B data to score. I have found that this case when statement doesn't work, times out connection to database etc.
What could be a more performant solution for this?
I have been able to get the results I wanted by using a for loop running each of the rules as an UPDATE query with the conditions in the WHERE clause. My code above now looks like this:
UPDATE table_with_data
SET NODE = 1
WHERE variable_1 = "Value1" ;

UPDATE table_with_data
SET NODE = 2
WHERE variable_1 = 2 AND variable_2 = 'Variable2_value1';

So now the 21k rules run as 21k update statements. This loop runs for a ridiculous amount of time, but it does the job. However, I don't think it is performant and want to optimize it.
I use:

snowflake: database
R: building tree and parsing rules.

Relevant questions I have seen, but don't have a similar issue:

Design pattern to convert tree-rules from Weka into SQL query - this would result in 21k functions. Don't feel it's maintainable or a good practice.
how to generate rules from decision tree in data mining? - this is the approach I have used.

Updating to add a toy example. This example has only 3 rules, so fairly simple. How would you include != in a lookup table for this, as I have rules that are negative.
-- Create sample table  
CREATE TABLE customer_data (  
    customer_id INT PRIMARY KEY,  
    purchase_frequency INT,  
    total_spent DECIMAL(10, 2),  
    last_purchase DATE,  
    customer_segment VARCHAR(255)  
);  
  
-- Insert sample data  
INSERT INTO customer_data (customer_id, purchase_frequency, total_spent, last_purchase, customer_segment) VALUES  
(1, 15, 1500.00, '2023-02-15', NULL),  
(2, 8, 750.00, '2023-02-10', NULL),  
(3, 3, 200.00, '2023-01-05', NULL),  
(4, 12, 1100.00, '2023-03-01', NULL),  
(5, 6, 600.00, '2023-02-20', NULL),  
(6, 7, 450.00, '2023-02-25', NULL),  
(7, 5, 400.00, '2023-01-01', NULL);  

-- case statement
CASE  
    WHEN purchase_frequency > 10 AND total_spent > 1000 THEN 'High Value'  
    WHEN purchase_frequency BETWEEN 5 AND 10 AND total_spent BETWEEN 500 AND 1000 THEN 'Medium Value'  
    WHEN purchase_frequency > 5 AND total_spent < 500 AND last_purchase != '2023-01-01' THEN 'Low Value'  
    ...  
END AS customer_segment  


How complex do the decisions get? Is it always variable_1 and variable_2 or are there more? If there aren't more then you could create a mapping table.

Could you clarify what database you use?

Sample data would help a lot. You may be able to create a rules lookup table, maybe it has 1m (still peanuts to Snowflake) combinations to capture all the rules. Then join to it. I have had to do the sequential update approach before when nested CASE's were getting too disgusting, but never with anything close to 21k.

@Error_2646 - Added in a toy example, and thanks for your suggestion. However, I have negative rules. Do you have any ideas on how to apply a lookup for it?

So now the 21k rules run as 21k update statements. Because cloud object storage cannot be updated in place like a disk-backed database, this approach is probably re-writing most if not all of the table's micropartitions 21k times. While you're investigating more permanent solutions, you could investigate writing the results append only to a separate table. That would be 21k inserts, which will minimize IO compared to 21k updates. Then perform a single update on the main table. All you'd need in the separate table is the PK of the row to change and the value for the NODE column.

My above comment is for a quick fix that should dramatically lower IO requirements. For a more elegant solution, I have a question. For the rules, are the comparisons always "and-ed" together or do they sometimes have "or" conditions? If they're always "and-ed" together, I would investigate using a procedural UDTF (JavaScript, Java, Python or Scala but not SQL) that implements a rules engine and reads the rules from a table. You can pass the entire contents of a small table (the 21k rules) into a UDTF parameter as a JSON variant provided it's under 16Mb (which it probably could be).

@GregPavlik - Thanks for the suggestions. My rules are always "and"-ed. I actually tried a SP in SQL script, but the time taken was similar as the CASE statement and abandoned that. However, you mention to construct the procedure in Python/Scala/Java/JS. Would performance be better? My impression was that under the hood the procedure would be converted to SQL-like  (as this is applied on a database).

@GregPavlik - Thanks for the suggestion to lower IO requirements. I didn't completely understand it, but I think I'm doing a variation of it. Want to check so that I can optimize this bit: After the first loop say 1 million of the billion rows were updated, I move these 1 million rows to another table. The remaining rules only have to deal with the 999 million rows.

@bullet_proof, I actually tried a SP in SQL script I would expect this, whether using Snowflake SQL Script or any other SP language. The difference is that a UDTF runs with the full parallelism of the warehouse. A stored procedure, if the logic is embedded in the SP code rather than something the SP calls, is not parallelized that way (not normally anyway, but that's a separate issue).

@bullet_proof the reason inserts are much faster than updates is that inserting 1000 rows will (for normal sized rows) create a single micropartition. By comparison, updating 1000 rows may wind up re-writing 1000 micropartitions if the rows are all in different micropartitions. We're here to help. If you want, you can have your Sales Engineer reach out to me internally and we can get on a call to discuss options.

Thanks @GregPavlik for this suggestion! Instead of the UPDATE, I did an INSERT into a new table, and run time for each loop. I found a channel to get through to a Sales engineer - would they be able to help for improving performance more for scaling to bigger datasets? Thanks again for your inputs!

You should consider a user-defined table function (UDTF). It's built for cases like these where the data is too large for a stored procedure.
